# Convert tree insert function to recursive function

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I have a tree and I would like to insert an element in my tree I have created a function that works, but I would like to build it in a recursive form how would I do that?

Here is my code.

```
'Inserer method puts the new data in the right place
    'in the tree if the data is not already present. In this case
    'method returns true to indicate that the insertion occurred
    'correctly. Otherwise, the method returns false.
    'Note that this method uses a non-recursive process.
    Public Function Inserer(laDonnee As T) As Boolean

        'If the root does not exist, then the tree is empty and the data
         'insert is placed in a new node that will become the
         'root.
        If m_laRacine Is Nothing Then
            m_laRacine = New NoeudBSTNR(laDonnee)
            Return True
        Else
            Dim leParcours As NoeudBSTNR
            Dim leParent As NoeudBSTNR

            leParcours = m_laRacine
            leParent = Nothing


            'Path of the tree keeping the parent of the node
            'current at each iteration. If the data to be inserted is
            'smaller than the data of the current node, the course
            'continue to the left. Otherwise, the route continues to
            ' the right.
            While leParcours IsNot Nothing
                leParent = leParcours
                If laDonnee.CompareTo(leParcours.Donnee) < 0 Then
                    leParcours = leParcours.FilsGauche
                Else
                    leParcours = leParcours.FilsDroit
                End If
            End While

            'At the end of the journey, the data to be inserted is placed in a
            'new child node on the left of the parent if it is no longer
            'small as the parent's data or in a child node to
            'parent's right if it is larger than the data of the
            'parent. In both cases, the method returns true. If the
            'data to insert is equal to the data of the parent, so
            'a duplicate is the method returns false to indicate that
            'insertion failed.
            If laDonnee.CompareTo(leParent.Donnee) = 0 Then
                Return False
            Else
                If laDonnee.CompareTo(leParent.Donnee) < 0 Then
                    leParent.FilsGauche = New NoeudBSTNR(laDonnee)
                Else
                    leParent.FilsDroit = New NoeudBSTNR(laDonnee)
                End If
                Return True
            End If
        End If
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love recursive algorithms.

A recursive function will usually have theses characteristics:

1. It works in a finite workspace (a single node in this case).
2. It can call itself to change it's workspace.

You could achieve what you want by modifying the overload of `Inserer`. For now you give this function a number and move on. You must have a number and a pointer. The reason for this is that for `Inserer` to be autonomous in it's work, it must "know" where to work.

Then, instead of iterating through all the nodes, `Inserer` can call itself to change it's workspace while it hasn't finished it's job yet.

You seem to know how to code, so I'll give you some pseudocode (also, I guess that you'll want to code your assignment yourself):

```
Inserer(laDonnee, Optional currentNode = Nothing) As Boolean
  if currentNode is nothing
    'root doesn't exist
    root = new node(laDonnee)
    return True
  end if

  'return false if the value already exist
  If laDonnee.CompareTo(currentNode.Donnee) = 0
    return false
  end if

  'create the new node or move along the tree
  If laDonnee.CompareTo(currentNode.Donnee) < 0
    if currentNode.FilsGauche is not null
      return Inserer(laDonnee, currentNode.FilsGauche)
    else
      currentNode.FilsGauche = new node(laDonnee)
      return true
  Else
    if currentNode.FilsDroit is not null
      return Inserer(laDonnee, currentNode.FilsDroit)
    else
      currentNode.FilsDroit = new node(laDonnee)
      return true
  End If
End
```

Now, you call this function by giving it a value, and `laRacine` (because you always start reading the tree at the root). First time it'll create a root, and the next times it'll examine if there is some space in both `filDroit` and `filGauche` and create the node if needed, or move along theses branches until it finds an empty node th fill.

I can give you VBNET code if you need to, but I think that if you wrote your own code so far you'll be able to pick this up. I'm available if you have further questions.

PS: I wrote Optional for the overload so you can call this function without giving it `laRacine`. This would be the right syntax:

```
Public Function Inserer(laDonnee As T, Optional currentNode As NoeudBSTNR = Nothing) As Boolean
```

But if you're not sure about that part you can ignore it and just give `laRacine` to your function when you call it to add a new value. It'll be the exact same end result. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I was able to esaly adapte de code but I have one more question I would also like the tree to be balanced I have two methodes Private Function PivoterAGauche(leNoeud As NoeudAVL) As NoeudAVL to pivot left and  Private Function PivoterADroite(leNoeud As NoeudAVL) As NoeudAVL
 to pivot right were should I call them to keep the tree balanced.

Comment: Assuming that you know everything else about balancing the tree, it would go like this: 1) insert a value.  2) find the first unbalanced node by "climbing up" the tree starting with the newly inserted value.  3) Rotate the unbalanced node using the right rotation depending on the actual case.

Comment: Of course this may not be enough to answer your follow-up question. If you need a more detailed answer I suggest that you write a new question, as this cannot be explained just as a comment.

Comment: I created a new question like you suggested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238949/avl-tree-how-to-balance-tree-on-insert

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Thanks for letting me know, I'll get to it later today if nobody else already did.